# Laravel Eloquent - Order by Model Method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model called "certificados" with this method to dinamically calculate the status:

```
public function vence()
{
  $vence = '';
  if ( null != $this->vencimiento && !$this->baja && !$this->renovado ) {
    $datetime1 = new \DateTime("now");
    $datetime2 = new \DateTime($this->vencimiento);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $vence = $interval->format('%r%a');
    if ( $vence == '+0' ) 
    {
        $vence = '0';   
    }

  }
  return $vence;
}
```

Is it possible in the index() of my controller ORDER BY **vence()**. Now I am ordering by **NUMERO**.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $busqueda = $request->input('busqueda');
    $certificados = Certificado::where('numero','like','%'.$busqueda.'%')
      ->orWhere('producto','like','%'.$busqueda.'%')
      ->orWhereHas('titular', function($q) use($busqueda)
        {
          $q->where('nombre', 'like','%'.$busqueda.'%');
        })
      ->orderBy('numero')
      ->paginate(config('constantes.general.paginacion'));
    return View('certificados.index')->with('certificados', $certificados);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If `vence` is not a field in your database, I don't think you can use it in your query. You might need to order the results after running the query.

Comment: Hi Camilo. And how can I order the results after?

Comment: You will need to work with [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections). I would try adding the `vence` field  as a [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your `Certificado` model and then using [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) or something similar.